# How to solve $(2x^2+y)\partial x+(xy^2-x)\partial y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve this kinda eq.?
$$(2x^2+y)\partial x+(xy^2-x)\partial y=0$$

first I check  if it is entire. (which is not because $M(x,y)=2x^2+y\quad and \quad N(x,y)=xy^2-x\quad thus \quad M_y=1\neq y^2-1=N_x$)
I tried to find integral factor.( which I couldn't because $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}$ doesnt respect to x and $\frac{M_y-N_x}{M}$ doesn't respect to y)
how do we approach?

(I may wrote  math. expressions wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Substitute

$$y = v x \rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = v + x v'$$

You will get an expression that requires an integrating factor to solve.

You will end up with:

$$v(x) = \pm ~ \dfrac{\sqrt{-4x^3 + c x^2 +1} + 1}{x^2}$$

Of course, to find the final solution, from the substitution above, you will have:

$$y(x) = v x$$

Comment: Another DE UV coming your way! +1

Comment: And another one here is on the way. :+)